# Line annotation from data on ggplotly object across facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have a ggplot bar graph which displays year on year population data from a certain location, and is faceted based on designation, e.g. Resident or Visitor:
[image: picture of bar graphs]

(Some bins are empty because there is no data from that period, which is expected).

The bar graph will be converted to a ggplotly object in order to place in a shiny app, where the end user will be able to change the location with a picker, and will be faceted by Status, i.e. Resident and Visitor.

What I want is a line and text annotation on the ggplotly object which shows the number of unique people per location from the same dataframe as the bar chart, as in my paint.net example below, and it matches the appropriate Status, e.g. data comes from residents_from_census for residents, and visitors_from_census for the visitor facet:

[image: image of facetted graphs with lines]

The value of the y-axis can't be hardcoded in, because it will change as the user changes location.

Minimum reproducible example with dummy dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

dummy <- data.frame(
  location = rep(c("317056", "317057"), 6),
  period = rep(c("2019_yoy", "2020_yoy", "2021_yoy"), 4),
  unique_agents = c(318, 219, NA, 1127, 34, 108, 2346, 113, 1546, 1112, NA, 0),
  Status = rep(c("Resident", "Visitor"), each = 6),
  visitors_from_census = rep(127, 12),
  residents_from_census = rep(643, 12)  
) %>% mutate(
  period = as.factor(period)
)

graph.object <- dummy %>%
  filter(
    location == "317056"
  ) %>% 
  arrange(
    period
  ) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = period,
      y = unique_agents,
      fill = period
    )
  ) + geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge()
  ) + facet_wrap(
    ~Status, ncol = 1
  )

# Convert to plotly object
ggplotly(graph.object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the horizontal line on the plot using `geom_hline`.

Here's what it will look like:

```
geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge()
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = dummy$unique_agents_from_census[1], show.legend = T) +
```

And to annotate the line you can use either `annotate` or `geom_text`.

```
geom_text(aes(x = dummy$period[1], y = dummy$unique_agents_from_census[1] + 10, label = paste("Census location", dummy$unique_agents_from_census[1])))
```

P.S: Please notice that I've passed only the first index in `geom_hline` and `geom_text` as you will need the same while moving to shiny.

The output:
[image]

**EDIT**
In Order to get the `hline` in the faceted plot, you'll need to manipulate the data frame a little bit.

I've added an extra column called `yintercet` so that it could be used in the `hline`.

Here's how you can do it:

```
dummy <- dummy %>%
  group_by(Status) %>%
  mutate(yintercept = ifelse((Status == "Resident"), residents_from_census[Status == "Resident"],
         visitors_from_census[Status == "Visitor"]))
```

I've used `ifelse` to check is the `Status`. And based on it column `yintercept` is filled with appropriate values.

The plot can be plotted using the following code:

```
graph.object <- dummy %>%
  filter(
    location == "317056"
  ) %>% 
  arrange(
    period
  ) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = period,
      y = unique_agents,
      fill = period
    )
  ) + geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge()
  ) +  facet_wrap(
    ~Status, ncol = 1
  ) + 
  geom_hline(data = dummy, aes(yintercept = yintercept), show.legend = T) +
  geom_text(data = dummy, aes(x = period[1], y = yintercept + 50, label = paste(Status, "from census: ", yintercept)))

ggplotly(graph.object)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I now need to facet the plot based on Resident/Visitor flag,  each with a different census total. I've edited by question accordingly.

Comment: I've edited the answer according to your new query. Please consider accepting it as an answer and upvoting. That'll help me a lot!

Comment: I've gotten around to implementing this now and the solution doesn't work very well - the text is very grainy and it doesn't sit neatly on the line, because of the +50 adding more or less space depending on the original amount, as you can see in this screenshot: https://tinypic.host/i/0546D